# handlebars integrating with angular 6

Tags: angular, handlebars.js

I am integrating handlebars.js with angular 6 and getting below error.

./node_modules/handlebars/lib/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in '\client\node_modules\handlebars\lib'

Please help me to find out exact solution.